# What could prevent Outlook 2007 from saving account passwords?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007

Got this e-mail from my dad this morning.

> My Outlook 2007 will not save my passwords for my email accounts and I have to input them every time I hit Send/Receive. I have tried everything that the Microsoft website says to do but it still has the same problem.
>   Have you run into this problem with Windows XP and if so, what do I need to do to fix it?

Nothing particular is popping to mind for me, unfortunately.  It seems Dad's probably dug through TechNet already, (he's savvy enough that I can safely presume that's what he means by "Microsoft's website") and still not found a working solution.

Do y'all have any ideas?

EDIT:  I'll write him back to get specifics on what he's already tried.  Just wanted to get this posted quick.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out? Or do you have an update regarding what he has already tried? Thanks!

Comment: @Kyle - Thanks for checking.  Still an open issue as far as I know, but haven't received any further details yet.

Comment: Cool @iszi, let me know when you update with what he has tried.

Comment: @Kyle - In the end, it seems like it had something to do with a corrupt user profile.  Dad created a new account and moved his files over, and it seems everything's working now.

Comment: Cool @Iszi, I'm glad he got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have him go into control panel and open *Mail*, under email accounts, select his account and click change, click more settings at the bottom right, under the security tab make sure "Always prompt for logon credentials" isn't checked.

[image]